# String or Binary DAta would be truncated on Delete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to delete a couple of rows

USING

SQL Server management studio, for 2 rows only i get the message

No rows were deleted

```
A problem occurred attempting to delete row #X
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: String or binary data would be truncated
The Statement has been terminated


Correct the errors and attempt to delete the row again or press ESC to cancel the change(s)
```

What could be happening while deleting the row ?

the keys are unique so that's not an issue

I've deleted the rows using manual DELETE statements but curious about what's going on here

any thoughts ?

this is using SQL 2008 R2 Express edition

UPDATE  - there are no triggers on the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running SQL Profiler while deleting through SSMS if you want to know exactly how it's deleting them.

Do you have a delete trigger on the table? It could be that one of the variables that you're logging into an audit table is longer when going through the GUI instead of through the query window.

In any event, providing the table definition and the rows being deleted might help others find a solution to your question.